# TrueType fonts won't persist in libGDX app

Tags: android, libgdx, truetype

I am using the stb-truetype library in my android application to render .ttf files to the screen by converting them to a BitmapFont. The fonts render perfectly fine on the initial run of the app. However, when I press the Home button and re-open the app (it resumes where it left off when I pressed the button), the program renders white boxes where each letter should be. This is the code I have used to generate the BitmapFont:

```
        font = TrueTypeFontFactory.createBitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Quadrats.ttf"), FONT_CHARACTERS, 75, 50, 5.65f, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    font.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    font.setScale(20 / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 17 / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Where `font` is a libGDX BitmapFont that has been declared at initialization.

I suspect the problem is to do with the whole Bundle savedInstanceState thing but I'm not sure exactly what I need to do make the fonts persist when reopening the activity. Anyone got any ideas?

Alternatively, does anyone know of a way to convert the ttf to a BitmapFont file that I can simply call from my app, without the need to include the stb libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about the `font` field?  Is it a static field?

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could simply convert the TrueType font to a Bitmap font before the application runs using BMFont. Here's the link: http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/